# UITextField and keyboard controls checking if field has data

Tags: ios, ios5, uitextfield

I am using BSKeyboard Controls to have a next/previous and done button above the keyboard on login fields for username and password.

What I want to achieve is:
- When one of the fields is blank the done button should say 'Done'
- When both fields have at least one character it should say 'Login'

I understand there are multiple ways to check a textfield contents, hasText isEqualToString !=nil etc. But I am trying to check characters here I guess.

I need to know what would be the best location to put an if statement and which to use.

My fields are

```
self.usernameField
self.passwordField
```

My Keyboard control is updated like this:

```
self.keyboardControls.doneTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"KeyboardControlsDone", @"test");
```

OR

```
self.keyboardControls.doneTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"KeyboardControlsLogin", @"test");
```

Updated Method:

```
NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

UITextField *otherTextField;
if (textField == self.passwordField)
{
    otherTextField = self.usernameField;
}
else
{
    otherTextField = self.passwordField;
}

if ([newText length] > 0 && [otherTextField.text length] > 0)
{
    self.keyboardControls.doneTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"KeyboardControlsLogin",@"Button for Keyboard Controls on Login page");
} else {
    self.keyboardControls.doneTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"KeyboardControlsDone", @"test");
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString:` of UITextFieldDelegate to execute whatever you want when the user enters a key.
Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

    UITextField *otherTextField;
    if (textField == self.passwordField)
    {
        otherTextField = self.usernameField;
    }
    else
    {
        otherTextField = self.passwordField;
    }

    if ([newText length] > 0 && [otherTextField.text length] > 0)
    {
//        Your code
    }
    return YES;
}
```

EDIT

Instead of using that delegate method,use the event editing changed. You have to set the action for that event with IB or by code, and it would look like this:

```
- (IBAction) textFieldEditingChanged
{
    if ([self.usernameField.text length] > 0 && [self.passwordField.text length] > 0)
    {
        self.keyboardControls.doneTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"KeyboardControlsLogin",@"Button for Keyboard Controls on Login page");
    } else {
        self.keyboardControls.doneTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"KeyboardControlsDone", @"test");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question text. What I am having difficulty with now is if you type into username, then type into password (this works fine button changes to login), but if you then clear password(or click back into username and clear username) it does not change back to Done.

Comment: You are right,that delegate method is not fired if the user clears the textfield, see solution in my edit.

Comment: I actually used the uitextfield clear method : - (BOOL)textFieldShouldClear:(UITextField *)textField to then change the button back to Done, either would work. Thanks